# Matching irregular datetimes (with missing datetimes) to regular datetime schedule

Tags: r, algorithm, datetime, match

Suppose `datetimes1` are datetimes at irregular intervals, and `datetimes2` are datetimes at regular intervals.  `datetimes1` have some missing datetimes, such as 5:10, as shown in the first table.

What I want is to try to match `datetimes1` to `datetimes2`, so that each `datetimes1` are close to `datetimes2` AND all `datetimes1` are in seemly correct rows.

At first, I tried rounding `datetimes1` to nearest 5 minutes and try to match them to `datetimes2`, but some datetimes are off by 3 minutes so they get rounded to incorrect values.

Next thing I tried was to find which `datetimes1` are exactly equal to `datetimes2` and match those `datetimes1` to `datetimes2` first, by setting `tolerance` to 0, then start increasing `tolerance` by one in every loop, and match the `datetimes1` which isn't matched yet to `datetimes2` which is off by specified `tolerance`.

The problem with this method is that both times 5:33 and 5:37 are off by 2 minutes from 5:35, so 5:33 gets matched to 5:35 first then 5:37 does not get included in the table.  See 2nd table for the results I got using the given code.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this problem?

What I want to see:

```
           datetimes1          datetimes2
1 2014-07-24 05:05:00 2014-07-24 05:05:00
2                <NA> 2014-07-24 05:10:00
3 2014-07-24 05:15:00 2014-07-24 05:15:00
4 2014-07-24 05:23:00 2014-07-24 05:20:00
5 2014-07-24 05:27:00 2014-07-24 05:25:00
6 2014-07-24 05:33:00 2014-07-24 05:30:00
7 2014-07-24 05:37:00 2014-07-24 05:35:00
8 2014-07-24 05:41:00 2014-07-24 05:40:00
9 2014-07-24 05:45:00 2014-07-24 05:45:00
```

But I got this instead:

```
           datetimes1          datetimes2
1 2014-07-24 05:05:00 2014-07-24 05:05:00
2                <NA> 2014-07-24 05:10:00
3 2014-07-24 05:15:00 2014-07-24 05:15:00
4                <NA> 2014-07-24 05:20:00
5 2014-07-24 05:23:00 2014-07-24 05:25:00
6 2014-07-24 05:27:00 2014-07-24 05:30:00
7 2014-07-24 05:33:00 2014-07-24 05:35:00
8 2014-07-24 05:41:00 2014-07-24 05:40:00
9 2014-07-24 05:45:00 2014-07-24 05:45:00
```

Here is my code:

```
irregulars <- c("2014-07-24 05:05",
                "2014-07-24 05:15",
                "2014-07-24 05:23",
                "2014-07-24 05:27",
                "2014-07-24 05:33",
                "2014-07-24 05:37",
                "2014-07-24 05:41",
                "2014-07-24 05:45")

df1 <- data.frame(datetimes <- as.POSIXct(irregulars, "GMT"))

regulars <- c("2014-07-24 05:05",
              "2014-07-24 05:10",
              "2014-07-24 05:15", 
              "2014-07-24 05:20",
              "2014-07-24 05:25",
              "2014-07-24 05:30",
              "2014-07-24 05:35",
              "2014-07-24 05:40",
              "2014-07-24 05:45")

df2 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(NA,length(regulars),2)),c("datetimes1","datetimes2"))
df2$datetimes2 <- as.POSIXct(regulars, "GMT")

# Match irregulars to regulars
for(tolerance in c(0:3)) {
  for(idx in which(!df1$datetimes %in% df2$datetimes1)) {
    dt <- abs(difftime(df2$datetimes2, df1$datetimes[idx], "GMT", "mins"))
    dt.min <- min(dt[is.na(df2$datetimes1)])
    if (dt.min > tolerance) next
    idx2 <- which(dt == dt.min)
    df2$datetimes1[idx2] <- df1$datetimes[idx]
  }
}

df2$datetimes1 <- as.POSIXct(df2$datetimes1, "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach. Suppose our matching algorithm is to find a time from a set of candidates that has the smallest absolute difference from a target `x`, on the condition that the difference has to be below a tolerance level (say 5 minutes, or 300 seconds):

```
closest <- function(x, candidates, tol = 300) {
  timediff <- abs(difftime(x, candidates, units = "secs"))
  if (all(timediff >= tol)) return(NA)
  candidates[which.min(timediff)]
}
```

The candidates in our case is the set of "irregulars", and our targets are the "regulars". The main idea here is to iterate through the "regulars", and whenever we find a match from the set of candidates, we remove it from the set of candidates:

```
candidates <- irregulars
out <- sapply(regulars, function(x) {
    matched <- closest(x, candidates, tol = 300)
    candidates <<- setdiff(candidates, matched)
    matched
})
```

Here's the complete MWE.  First set up the time vectors:

```
irregulars <- c("2014-07-24 05:05",
                "2014-07-24 05:15",
                "2014-07-24 05:23",
                "2014-07-24 05:27",
                "2014-07-24 05:33",
                "2014-07-24 05:37",
                "2014-07-24 05:41",
                "2014-07-24 05:45")

regulars <- c("2014-07-24 05:05",
              "2014-07-24 05:10",
              "2014-07-24 05:15", 
              "2014-07-24 05:20",
              "2014-07-24 05:25",
              "2014-07-24 05:30",
              "2014-07-24 05:35",
              "2014-07-24 05:40",
              "2014-07-24 05:45")
```

Define the `closest` function and iterate:

```
closest <- function(x, candidates, tol = 600) {
  timediff <- abs(difftime(x, candidates, units = "secs"))
  if (all(timediff >= tol)) return(NA)
  candidates[which.min(timediff)]
}

candidates <- irregulars
out <- sapply(regulars, function(x) {
    matched <- closest(x, candidates, tol = 300)
    candidates <<- setdiff(candidates, matched)
    matched
})
```

Display the output:

```
data.frame(datetimes1 = out,
           datetimes2 = names(out),
           row.names = NULL)
#        datetimes1       datetimes2
# 1 2014-07-24 05:05 2014-07-24 05:05
# 2             <NA> 2014-07-24 05:10
# 3 2014-07-24 05:15 2014-07-24 05:15
# 4 2014-07-24 05:23 2014-07-24 05:20
# 5 2014-07-24 05:27 2014-07-24 05:25
# 6 2014-07-24 05:33 2014-07-24 05:30
# 7 2014-07-24 05:37 2014-07-24 05:35
# 8 2014-07-24 05:41 2014-07-24 05:40
# 9 2014-07-24 05:45 2014-07-24 05:45
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the irregular time can never be 5 minutes apart from the regular time, you can iterate over both vectors and choose only when the difference is less than 5 minutes:

```
i=1
j=1
while(i<=nrow(df2) & j<=nrow(df1))
{
    d <-difftime(df2$datetimes2[i], df1$datetimes[j], "GMT",unit="mins")

    if (abs(d) < 5) {
            df2$datetimes1[i] <-  df1$datetimes[j]
            j=j+1
            i=i+1
        } else if(d>0) j=j+1
    else i=i+1


}
df2$datetimes1 <- as.POSIXct(df2$datetimes1, "GMT", origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")


> df2
           datetimes1          datetimes2
1 2014-07-24 05:05:00 2014-07-24 05:05:00
2                <NA> 2014-07-24 05:10:00
3 2014-07-24 05:15:00 2014-07-24 05:15:00
4 2014-07-24 05:23:00 2014-07-24 05:20:00
5 2014-07-24 05:27:00 2014-07-24 05:25:00
6 2014-07-24 05:33:00 2014-07-24 05:30:00
7 2014-07-24 05:37:00 2014-07-24 05:35:00
8 2014-07-24 05:41:00 2014-07-24 05:40:00
9 2014-07-24 05:45:00 2014-07-24 05:45:00
```